# Angular LoadingService strategy throwing a Expression changed error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've tried reading up on this and a lot of suggestions to fix this but I'm out of luck. I guess my whole strategy is just bad somehow though I do not realize how.

I have a *LoadingService* that holds a *BehaviourSubject* of **Boolean**. I like to display a loading screen instead of the *router-outlet* when doing API calls and setting up the view. So I just wanted to set the behavior after that is done which switches from the loading screen to the router outlet.

Here is the service:

```
export class LoadingService {
  private emitLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.emitLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  }

  get loading$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.emitLoading.asObservable();
  }

  public setLoading(newValue: boolean): void {
    this.emitLoading.next(newValue);
  }
}
```

And my bootstrapped app component

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <div *ngIf="loading$ | async">
      <h1>...Loading<h1>
    <div>
    <div [hidden]="loading$ | async">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where **loading$** is exposed from that loading service through the app component

```
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(
    private loader: LoadingService
  ) { }

  get loading$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loader.loading$;
  }
}
```

And I route straight ahead to a component that sets loading to false. I've tried a few different strategies here. `ngOnInit()`, `ngAfterViewInit()` , doing the `ChangeDetectorRed.detectChanges()` but nothing works.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.loader.setLoading(false);
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

I guess I don't understand the complexity here, or I'm using the Subject wrong. Anyone who can say straight out that this is a bad strategy, or has a way to make it work?

[Here is a stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-error)

Comment: In essence, you are receiving this error because your app.component.ts is loaded with the variable `loading$`, but when angular is rendering the child components, `loading$` changes.

Comment: Try something like that, above your constructor in AppComponent: loading$ = this.loader.loading$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my comment, the reason you are receiving this error is because your `app.component.ts` is loaded with the variable `loading$`, but when angular is rendering the child components, `loading$` changes, therefore:

> the expression has changed after it was checked

What I would recommend is to always show the `router-outlet`, but instead, display a loading overlay when the routing is navigating.

I have updated your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-error-guo41n) which now displays this overlay when you press submit. This should help in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So is it because I'm changing something on the parent, but in your solution you are changing a value on a "sibling" if we could say so.

Comment: Siblings are normally okay, it’s normally when you change an async value on the parent (used by html I believe) that causes the issue.